# uploading all files in the folder using ftp

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu, ftp

I'm trying to copy a folder from my computer to my android phone using ftp. After I login, I try `put *` or `put *.mp3` but it doesn't work well.

I am using command line in ubuntu linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `mput` rather than `put`.

Comment: And you might want to execute the command `prompt` first for avoiding user confirmation.